# Difference of last modified date and created in seconds- formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, lastmodifieddate, createddate

When a record is created and **trigger executes (after insert)- updating a field**, I want to calculate the time **difference between the last modified date and the created date in seconds.** If it's greater than 10 seconds update the field as true else false. Can someone tell how to calculate in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createdDate-LastModifiedDate
```

Returns the difference in the number of days - it's like yesterday- today - 1

If you multiply by 24 (24 hours a day ) returns the value in hours

then by 60 (60 minutes) returns the value in minutes

then again another 60 (60 seconds) returns the value in seconds

Difference in seconds

```
(createdDate-lastModifiedDate)*24*60*60
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem I was having - creating a formula checkbox to determine if a record had been updated or not, labeled "IsUpdated". Originally tried just the simple formula:

```
CreatedDate <> LastModifiedDate
```

But that always came back TRUE - assuming due to milliseconds difference.

Solution I found to work instead was individually comparing each piece of the DateTime fields, first matching the dates, then breaking the timestamp into Hours and Minutes for comparison.

```
NOT(
 DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) = DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) &&
 HOUR(   TIMEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)) = HOUR(   TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)) &&
 MINUTE( TIMEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)) = MINUTE( TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. Will check the HOUR and MINUTE